# Cloudfront doesn't seem to boost site's performance

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

My Wordpress site used s3 for images. Now I've integrated it with cloudfront distribution hoping that it would further boost the performance but its has dropped drastically.

As I checked, the cloudfront distribution is working as in it can load object/image from the cloudfront domain. But I noticed the images in the site refering to the previous s3 link/path not the cloudfront domain.

So is my site really loaded with cloudfront and how do I verify that. If it is then why is it slowing down the performance.What is the proper way to increase it?

Answer (score 2):

Cloudfront is more like a caching mechanism and the way it speeds up your website is by caching it for some time close to the source that is performing the request.

One of the things Cloudfront does is replace all URLs that points to an origin by a custom DNS ending in *.cloudfront.net or one that you provided.
URLs that point somewhere else from this source are not cached and it includes S3.

Theres nothing wrong by using S3 and the problem surely lies somewhere else.

To verify that your Cloudfront distribution is working correctly you can use a tool like Postman or curl to get the headers returned from your page.

You should have a header named `X-Cache` and it usually responds with:
`X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront` or `X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront`.

If you get many misses your config is probably not optimal.

You should also check the price class used in your distribution.
The price class will let you know what regions your website is being cached.
Please check this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/#On-demand_Pricing) and a bit further down you see the price class types:

- Price Class 100 being in United States, Canada and Europe
- Price Class 200 being in everywhere except Australia and South America
- Price Class All being in all regions available

As a side note you should post images showing the origin and behavior configurations that you did to enhance your question.